# I accidentally deleted Macintosh HD while installing Windows?

Tags: macos, mac, recovery

I installed Windows on my Mac through bootcamp but I accidentally deleted Macintosh HD in the process. I tried to use the internet recovery but it stopped and says

> apple.com/support  -2104F"

Please help me. I need this computer for school and I can't access the internet on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can Google multiple ways of creating boot-able media for OS X that you can use in Recovery Mode without having to use Internet Recovery.  Also, if you have a Time Machine backup, you could probably restore from that.

There's a chance your Master Boot Record is all messed up.  It may be a good idea to completely wipe the drive before doing this so that it gets partitioned correctly in the process.

Unless there are very specific scenarios (such as extremely limited host resources), this day in age, I really don't understand the reason for dual-booting when you can just as easily *(and much more safely)* install Windows as a virtual machine using VMware Fusion or Virtualbox.

Comment: The protective MBR has nothing to do with OS X. Windows uses it, but OS X does not.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard - so you are saying that if you are dual-booting Windows and OS X, you have no MBR? See [this link](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) and [http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/).  It seems it's a hybrid GUID/MBR partition table -- which I suppose could easily get messed up in a situation such as this.

Comment: OS X uses GPT (part of the UEFI standard), which contains a protective MBR to prevent non-GPT-aware OSes (such as Windows when installed in BIOS-mode) from damaging the disk, and to allow you to actually install said OSes which require MBR. OS X will boot, no matter what's in the protective MBR, because OS X does not use it.